# MS-Dos access to domain shared folder on server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, ms-dos

I have a quite old CNC machine and need to gain access to a shared folder on Windows Server 2012 R2. It is perfect works with a shared folder on a non-domain server where a guest account is turned on.

But currently, I need to move this share on a domain fileserver and here I have an issue.

I tried to create a local account and use it on the CNC, without any success.
I tried to allow guest, everyone and ANONYMOUS LOGON access to the folder, still no success.

I found topic with the guide on how to change all local security policies, did that and still no success.

Don't know what to do next. Is there a chance that someone in 2020 knows how to get access from Ms-Dos to a server share?

**Update 1**

```
> Get-SmbServerConfiguration

AnnounceServer: False
AsynchronousCredits: 64
AuditSmb1Access: False
AutoShareServer: True
AutoShareWorkstation: True
CachedOpenLimit: 5
AnnounceComment:
EnableDownlevelTimewarp: False
EnableLeasing: True
EnableMultiChannel: True
EnableStrictNameChecking: True
AutoDisconnectTimeout: 0
DurableHandleV2TimeoutInSeconds: 30
EnableAuthenticateUserSharing: False
EnableForcedLogoff: True
EnableOplocks: True
EnableSecuritySignature: False
ServerHidden: True
IrpStackSize: 15
KeepAliveTime: 2
MaxChannelPerSession: 32
MaxMpxCount: 50
MaxSessionPerConnection: 16384
MaxThreadsPerQueue: 20
MaxWorkItems: 1
NullSessionPipes: AKS
NullSessionShares: COMCF
OplockBreakWait: 35
PendingClientTimeoutInSeconds: 120
RequireSecuritySignature: False
EnableSMB1Protocol: True
EnableSMB2Protocol: True
Smb2CreditsMax: 2048
Smb2CreditsMin: 128
SmbServerNameHardeningLevel: 0
TreatHostAsStableStorage: False
ValidateAliasNotCircular: True
ValidateShareScope: True
ValidateShareScopeNotAliased: True
ValidateTargetName: True
EncryptData: False
RejectUnencryptedAccess: True
```

**Update 2**
I noticed that when I'm conecting from a windows 10 computer with an incorrect username, on the server event logs stored in *Application and service logs - Microsoft - Windows - SMBServer security (Error SMB Session Authentication Failure)*

But when I trying to connect from MS-Dos station logs stored in *Windows logs - Security (Audit Failure)*

Comment: What is the output of `Get-SmbServerConfiguration`

Comment: Added Update 1 in the post